# How do I translate a math formula to python code?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to translate this formula into python:

```
x = b + (sqrt((b^2)-1)) / 2a
```

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
x = b + (math.sqrt((b ** 2) - 1 )) / (2 * a)
```

Comment: Operator precedence in Python. Exponent gets first priority. This works too: x = b + (math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 1 )) / (2 * a). Without the inner bracket for b ** 2

Comment: If b Is zero ir raises ValueError

Comment: Thanks @Cheche . If the formula deals with square root of negative numbers also, using the cmath library instead of math, seems like a possible solution. This takes care of the b = 0 case.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically correct this solution is

```py
import math
import cmath
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    if b == 0:
        f = (cmath.sqrt(b ** 2 - 1 )) / (2 * a)
    else:
        f = (math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 1 )) / (2 * a)
    return b + f, b -f

print(quadratic(1, 2, 3))
```

This will give you the two roots.

You can access the roots by indexing:

```py
my_roots = quadratic(1, 2, 3)
x_1 = my_roots[0]
x_2 = my_roots[1]
```

By using a Python function , you can re-use this code.

Comment: If b Is zero ir raises ValueError.

Comment: @Cheche -- Appreciate the note and change

Comment: Yes, if a=0 is not quadratic any more. So it would be nice to catch and raise a nice error message in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well. No need to import any library. 
Assuming `a != 0`.

When `b >= 1`:

```py
x = b + (((b ** 2) - 1 ) ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
```

> NOTE: You should ideally have two roots for **`sqrt(b^2 - 1)`**. Your function should return both values. Now, I am guessing that, under certain prior knowledge you have decided to only keep the positive root.

When `b == 0`, you get two roots. Note that `sqrt(-1) = j or -j` (complex roots).

```py
x = (+1j) / (2 * a) # positive root
# OR
x = (-1j) / (2 * a) # negative root
```

More generally, when `b**2 < 1`, you get two complex roots.

```py
x = b + (k*1j) ((1 - (b ** 2)) ** 0.5) / (2 * a) 
# positive root: k = +1
# OR
# negative root: k = -1
```

Comment: @james-jameson Please take a look at this option and let me know if you have any questions.